# Raspberry pi 2 wifi connection

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, wifi

I have a raspberry pi 2 with a Edimax wifi dongle.

It has Raspbian GNU/Linus 8 (jessie)

It will not connect to the WiFi although it sees the network.

The network is a WEP, is this a problem?

I get the error:

"The website at http://google.com seems to be unavailable. The precise error was: Error resolving 'google.com'. Temporary failure in name resolution. It could be temporarily switched off or moved to a new address. Don't forget to check that your internet connection is working correctly."

How can I get my Pi connected to WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal on the Pi

sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

Make the file look like this:

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Both of those are Google DNS servers

After you edit the file try accessing the internet.

Comment: Sorry each nameserver should be on a seperate line, it sounds like the issue is DNS related.

Comment: Does it have to do with using Jessie and a WEP WiFi or have those been compatible in the past?

Comment: in terminal run: ping 8.8.8.8 do you get a response?

Comment: Ok that confirms that the issue is not DNS related, what exactly happens when you try to connect to the wifi, do you receive any error message? What is the terminal output from command: sudo ifconfig wlan0

Comment: Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 74:da:38:66:1b:bc  inet6 addr: fe80::73e3:11e:79c5:ccca/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX Packets:0 errors:0 dropped:30 overruns:0 frame:0    TX Packers:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes: 0 (0.0 B) TX bytes: 0 (0.0 B)

Comment: That means it's definitely not connected to a network and has not received an IP address. How are you trying to connect the Wifi? From a GUI or configure it from the terminal, does it produce an error specific to the wifi connection?

Comment: I tried the GUI, no error produced but the icon remains with a gray X saying its not connected

Comment: Does your WEP SSID have a password?

Answer (score 0):

I've always found WPA/WPA2 easy to setup and use, but people have reported WEP sometimes tricky to setup on Linux

You didn't say if you had a password or not on your SSID, but I'll assume you do.

If you can open a terminal session and then open/create wpa.conf file, try to manually add your network and restart it.

```
>sudo nano /etc/wpa.conf
```

Then add these lines if they're not already in there

```
network = {
   ssid="yourSSID"
   key_mgmt=NONE
   wep_key0="yourWiFipassword"
}
```

Close file and save it

Enable your WiFi Adaptor

```
>sudo ifup wlan0
```

Check wireless connections to see if it's listed and running

```
>iwconfig
```